# Shiny : Change the value of a select input

Tags: r, input, shiny

I have several input files contains n columns of coordinates, How could I design a select input panel in shiny in a way that my choices are the number of columns in my input file ?
for example once I read a zipfile which has 5 files of coordinates, In output I wanna say show the map related to coordinates in file 1 or file 2 or ... this means that my select input panel should show me 5 option.
If I read a zipfile with 100 file I wanna get drop down with 100 choices !
How could I do that ? I have checked [this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateSelectInput.html) but I don't know how to adapt it !

here is an example of my code . Unfortunately, It's not reproducible but reduced the complexity to be easy to understand :

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  fileInput("File","upload your file"),

  selectInput("Select1", "Select input",c())
  mainPanel(tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", ".tab-content {overflow: visible;}")),
  leafletOutput("mymap"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  coor <- reactive( {infile=input$File

                    if (is.null(infile))
                      return(NULL)
                    temp_files <- unzip(infile$datapath)
                    T=length(temp_files)
                    A_new=c();for(i in 1:T){A_new[[i]]=c()}
                    for(i in 1:T){
                      .
                      .
                      .
                      A_new[[i]]= ...
                    }
                    result <- list(A_new=A_new,T=T);
                    return(result);

                })

  observe({
    x <- input$File
    if (is.null(x))
      x <- character(0)
    map=coor()
    updateSelectInput(session, "Select1",
                      label = paste("Select input label", map$T),
                      choices = map$A_new,
                      selected = tail(map$A_new, 1)
    )
  })
}
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
  infile=input$File
  if (is.null(infile))
    return(NULL)
  a2=coor()
  leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles("OpenTopoMap", group = "MapQuestOpen.Aerial") %>%
    addMarkers(data =a2$A_new[[1]],~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(mag), label = ~as.character(Name))%>% 

    addMeasure()
})
```

In reactive function I read my file , do the calculations and getting my `A_new[[i]]` files which looks like this :

```
A_new[[1]]
       long      lat    mag
1  60.20424 34.61457 1100.0
2  60.20739 34.61155 1098.3
3  60.21058 34.60852 1099.7
4  60.21382 34.60544 1100.5
5  60.21700 34.60239 1100.0
6  60.22039 34.59930 1102.7
7  60.22388 34.59596 1103.0
8  60.22743 34.59245 1101.3
9  60.20323 34.60650 1080.0
10 60.20653 34.60346 1080.0
11 60.20966 34.60040 1080.8
12 60.21277 34.59748 1082.7
13 60.21590 34.59462 1084.1
14 60.21890 34.59161 1083.1
```

I wanna have this A_new[[i]] in select input and then tell the  `output$mymap`
returns the relevant map.
currently since I was not able to design select input options in map output I just show the first `A_new[[i]]` which is `A_new[[1]]`

Comment: What is the problem? Show the code that is giving you problems. Reproducible if possible.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have put the sample code with description, I hope its more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to upload any CSV using fileinput?
I have tried a solution using fileinput for reading CSV and re-actively changes the column name in dropdownlist(selectInput).

Upload 1st CSV with 4 column

[image]

Where 4 columns are showing in list

Now again upload a csv with 21 columns

[image]

Which shows 21 columns..

Code:
ui.r

```
library(shiny)

fluidPage(

  fileInput("file","Upload your CSV",multiple = FALSE),
  wellPanel(
    tags$h3("Select the parameters below"),
    checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
    checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
    radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
  ),

  uiOutput("list_item")
)
```

Server.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)

  })




  output$list_item<-renderUI({
    f<-data()
    selectInput("selected_list","Select from the list",choices = as.list(colnames(f)))
  })



})
```

if you want to use the upadateselectinput I can do that on this also..